# JqGrid set column width not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

I am trying to implement an grid with JqGrid.

I am not able to align the column width with the header width As the column data is too big to accommodate there. Is it possible to hide the column value if it exceeded the Header width. Below is my code snippet.

```
    $("#tblscheduleScan").jqGrid({
data: data,
datatype: 'local',
width: 1025,
colNames: ['Chosen Repo', 'Protex Project Name', 'Next Scheduled Scan', 'Recurrence Pattern', 'Modify'],
colModel: [{
  name: 'scannedPath',
  shrinkToFit: false
}, {
  name: 'projectName',
  shrinkToFit: false
}, {
  name: 'nextScanDate',
  shrinkToFit: false
}, {
  name: 'scheduleType',
  shrinkToFit: false
}, {
  name: 'Modify',
  align: 'center',
  classes: 'clickGridLink',
  shrinkToFit: false
}],
sortname: 'projectName',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "asc",
caption: '<h3>Scan Schedules</h3>',
height: 'auto',
gridview: true,
autoencode: true,
onCellSelect: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
  //var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
  if (iCol === 'Edit') {
    modifyScheduleScan(data[rowid - 1]);

  }
}


});
```

[image]

If I try to set the width Manually it is not working in google chrome browser but works fine in Firefox.

```
colModel: [
                                {name: 'scannedPath', width: 50, shrinkToFit: false},
                                {name: 'projectName', width: 95, shrinkToFit: false},
                                {name: 'nextScanDate', width: 30, shrinkToFit: false},
                                {name: 'scheduleType', width: 27, shrinkToFit: false},
                                {name: 'Modify', align: 'center', classes: 'clickGridLink', width: 10, shrinkToFit: false}
                            ]
```

Comment: `shrinkToFit: false` is the option of jqGrid and not the property of `colModel`.  If you set *explicit* `width` value like `width: 1025` without specifying of `shrinkToFit: false` then jqGrid extend of shrink the columns till the specified value (`1025`). Please write **always** which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: @Oleg I am using old jqgrid version 3.6. I have removed  shrinkToFit: false from col model. but still not working